# How Do I Make a Static IP with WLAN0?

Tags: server, wireless

I am trying to set a static IP address for my server, but what ifconfig is returning is leaving me a little bit confused:

If I run the command

```
ifconfig
```

I see that wlan0 is the only returned option that is sending and receiving packets besides the local loopback. This should be, as I am using a PCI adapter in my desktop in order to access the internet wirelessly. (I know this is not the most efficient way - learning purposes)

The problem is, I do not know how to configure /etc/network/interfaces with a wlan0  address; no matter where I look on the internet, they all say to use eth0, but I am not using Ethernet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see things like https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html but this really is not wlan0 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eth0` and `wlan0` are interface names but the general options for them should be the same, if you want to configure your `wlan0` interface for static IP you can do so using the same terminology of the information you see in the internet referring to `eth0`.

They are just names for the interfaces, nothing else. The name of your wireless interface in your system is `wlan0` use that while editing it but the rest (IP address, subnet masks, broadcasts...) are common options for any interface.

If you are not so confident in editing the `interfaces` by hand you can also use `nm-connection-editor` to edit your wireless (and much more).

Open a terminal and typo `gksudo nm-connection-editor` or the same after you pressed `Alt`+`F2` in your desktop.

Comment: Saw that you referred to *server* so probably you are not running a desktop so the last part of the answer will not do for you, still its useful and can be used for ppl running servers with a desktop.

Comment: gksudo nm-connection-editor doesn't do anything.